# FInd (X, Y) pairs and associated Z coordinates

Tags: python, list

I have a list of lists `DataCoord`:

```
[nodeID, X, Y, Z]
```

with multiple rows. Some nodes will have the same `X` and `Y` coordinates and different `Z` coordinate. For example, say I have:

```
Pair (X,Y) = (0,0):
[1, 0, 0, 0,]: level 0
[m, 0, 0, 200]: level m
[n, 0, 0, 100]: level n #the DataCoord list may not be ordered
```

I'd like to identify and sort the different `z`levels for this `(x,y)` pair.
And the same for other parts which share the same `X` and `Y` coordinates.

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT:
as an example of `DataCoord`:

```
[['173', '0.', '0.', '0.'], ['183', '1000.', '0.', '0.'], ['184', '0.', '1000.', '0.'], ['194', '1000.', '1000.', '0.'], ['195', '0.', '0.', '1000.'], ['205', '1000.', '0.', '1000.'], ['206', '0.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['216', '1000.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['217', '0.', '0.', '2000.'], ['227', '1000.', '0.', '2000.'], ['228', '0.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['238', '1000.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['239', '0.', '0.', '3000.'], ['249', '1000.', '0.', '3000.'], ['250', '0.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['260', '1000.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['261', '0.', '0.', '4000.'], ['271', '1000.', '0.', '4000.'], ['272', '0.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['282', '1000.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['283', '0.', '0.', '0.'], ['293', '0.', '1000.', '0.'], ['294', '1000.', '0.', '0.'], ['304', '1000.', '1000.', '0.'], ['305', '0.', '0.', '1000.'], ['315', '0.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['316', '1000.', '0.', '1000.'], ['326', '1000.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['327', '0.', '0.', '2000.'], ['337', '0.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['338', '1000.', '0.', '2000.'], ['348', '1000.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['349', '0.', '0.', '3000.'], ['359', '0.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['360', '1000.', '0.', '3000.'], ['370', '1000.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['371', '0.', '0.', '4000.'], ['381', '0.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['382', '1000.', '0.', '4000.'], ['392', '1000.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['436', '-1000.', '0.', '0.'], ['446', '0.', '0.', '0.'], ['447', '-1000.', '1000.', '0.'], ['457', '0.', '1000.', '0.'], ['458', '-1000.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['468', '0.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['469', '-1000.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['479', '0.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['480', '-1000.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['490', '0.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['491', '-1000.', '0.', '0.'], ['501', '-1000.', '1000.', '0.'], ['502', '-1000.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['512', '0.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['513', '-1000.', '0.', '1000.'], ['523', '0.', '0.', '1000.'], ['524', '-1000.', '0.', '2000.'], ['534', '0.', '0.', '2000.'], ['535', '-1000.', '0.', '3000.'], ['545', '0.', '0.', '3000.'], ['546', '-1000.', '0.', '4000.'], ['556', '0.', '0.', '4000.'], ['557', '-1000.', '0.', '1000.'], ['567', '-1000.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['568', '-1000.', '0.', '3000.'], ['578', '-1000.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['579', '-1000.', '0.', '2000.'], ['589', '-1000.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['590', '-1000.', '0.', '4000.'], ['600', '-1000.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['687', '0.', '2000.', '0.'], ['697', '1000.', '2000.', '0.'], ['698', '0.', '2000.', '1000.'], ['708', '1000.', '2000.', '1000.'], ['709', '0.', '2000.', '2000.'], ['719', '1000.', '2000.', '2000.'], ['720', '0.', '2000.', '3000.'], ['730', '1000.', '2000.', '3000.'], ['731', '0.', '2000.', '4000.'], ['741', '1000.', '2000.', '4000.'], ['742', '0.', '1000.', '0.'], ['752', '0.', '2000.', '0.'], ['753', '1000.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['763', '1000.', '2000.', '1000.'], ['764', '1000.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['774', '1000.', '2000.', '3000.'], ['775', '1000.', '1000.', '0.'], ['785', '1000.', '2000.', '0.'], ['786', '1000.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['796', '1000.', '2000.', '2000.'], ['797', '1000.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['807', '1000.', '2000.', '4000.'], ['808', '-1000.', '1000.', '0.'], ['818', '-1000.', '2000.', '0.'], ['819', '0.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['829', '0.', '2000.', '1000.'], ['830', '0.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['840', '0.', '2000.', '2000.'], ['841', '0.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['851', '0.', '2000.', '3000.'], ['852', '0.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['862', '0.', '2000.', '4000.'], ['863', '-1000.', '2000.', '0.'], ['873', '0.', '2000.', '0.'], ['874', '-1000.', '2000.', '1000.'], ['884', '0.', '2000.', '1000.'], ['885', '-1000.', '2000.', '2000.'], ['895', '0.', '2000.', '2000.'], ['896', '-1000.', '2000.', '3000.'], ['906', '0.', '2000.', '3000.'], ['907', '-1000.', '2000.', '4000.'], ['917', '0.', '2000.', '4000.'], ['918', '-1000.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['928', '-1000.', '2000.', '1000.'], ['929', '-1000.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['939', '-1000.', '2000.', '3000.'], ['940', '-1000.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['950', '-1000.', '2000.', '2000.'], ['951', '-1000.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['961', '-1000.', '2000.', '4000.']]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop over your values and collect the Z coordinates per X, Y pair; using [`collections.defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) makes this a little easier, setting the default to an empty `set` for each key:

```
from collections import defaultdict

levels = defaultdict(set)

for node_id, x, y, z in list_of_datacoords:
    levels[x, y].add(z)
```

Now `levels` is a dictionary mapping `x, y` coordinates to a set of unique `z` values.

For your example input, that results in:

```
>>> pprint(dict(levels))
{('-1000.', '0.'): set(['0.', '1000.', '2000.', '3000.', '4000.']),
 ('-1000.', '1000.'): set(['0.', '1000.', '2000.', '3000.', '4000.']),
 ('-1000.', '2000.'): set(['0.', '1000.', '2000.', '3000.', '4000.']),
 ('0.', '0.'): set(['0.', '1000.', '2000.', '3000.', '4000.']),
 ('0.', '1000.'): set(['0.', '1000.', '2000.', '3000.', '4000.']),
 ('0.', '2000.'): set(['0.', '1000.', '2000.', '3000.', '4000.']),
 ('1000.', '0.'): set(['0.', '1000.', '2000.', '3000.', '4000.']),
 ('1000.', '1000.'): set(['0.', '1000.', '2000.', '3000.', '4000.']),
 ('1000.', '2000.'): set(['0.', '1000.', '2000.', '3000.', '4000.'])}
```

You can now get a sorted list of levels per `x, y` pair:

```
for (x, y), z in levels.iteritems():
    z = sorted(z)
    # now you have x, y and a sorted list of `z` values.
```

The `pprint()` call above already printed the sets in sorted order; that is because `pprint()` sorts the output of python sequences by default.

Comment: Martijn However, the z levels will change with different pairs of x,y.... will this work in that case?

Comment: @jpcgandre: This code collects `z` levels *per `(x, y)` pair*. It doesn't matter that different pairs have different z levels, because that is already handled.

Comment: Martijn: I've ran the code for this case: four different pairs of (x,y) and only one row of z levels (the same for each pair). The code returned `z` with the only one row of `z` levels. But in the case of multiple `z`levels how can I "map" the pair of (x,y) to the associated `z` levels?

Comment: @jpcgandre: This code creates a *`set`* for each pair of `(x, y)` so additional `z` levels are handled automatically. Only unique values for `z` are retained. You could replace `set` with `list` to get all `z` level values, duplicates and all.

Comment: Martijn: I'll try with list. P.S.: I supplied an example of `list_of_datacoords`.
I've ran with `defaultdict(list)` and I got this error: `levels[x, y].add(z)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'add'`

Comment: @jpcgandre: Replace `.add()` (a `set` method) with `.append()` (a `list` method).

Comment: with the example I've gave, the result of `z` is `['0.', '1000.', '2000.', '3000.', '4000.']`. I'd like to be able to use what you got by `pprint(dict(levels))`. If possible I'd like to use something like this to write the different sine shape functions between different z levels: `if coordX,coordY == levels(x,y):
if coordZ>=levels(z) and coordZ<levels(z):
....` Is it possible? Thanks!!

Comment: I've no idea, because I am not following you. Perhaps you need to post a new question here on SO?

Comment: I've added information in this question. If it is not clear I'll redo it. thanks

Comment: hope it is better explained

Comment: Posted new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16233025/map-and-work-with-x-y-pairs-and-associated-z-coordinates