# Map and work with (X, Y), (X,Z) and (Y,Z) pairs and associated X, Y or Z coordinates

Tags: python

I have a list of lists `nLedgers` - a 3D cloud of points:

```
[nodeID, X, Y, Z]
```

with multiple rows. Some nodes will have the same `X` and `Y` coordinates and different `Z` coordinate.

I'd like to, first identify the different `Z` coordinates which have the same `X` and `Y` coordinates.
Then the same for `X`, and finally for `Y`.

Then, using those `(X,Y)`, `(X,Z)` or `(Y,Z)` pairs and different `Z`, `Y`or `X` levels I'd like to change the `x` and `y` coordinates of a second list (`nodes`).

The changes should respect the following:

```
1) For x,y,z in `nodes`, if x=X and y=Y and Z level 1 <=z< Z level 2:
   change x and y coordinates between consecutive `Z` levels, for each pair of `(X,Y)` coordinates.

2) For x,y,z in `nodes`, if x=X and Y level 1 <=y< Y level 2:
   change x coordinates between consecutive `Y` levels, for each pair of `(Y,Z)` coordinates.

3) For x,y,z in `nodes`, if y=Y and X level 1 <=x< X level 2:
   change y coordinates between consecutive `X` levels, for each pair of `(X,Z)` coordinates.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Based on previous posts I have the following code:

```
from ast import literal_eval
nLedgers=[[literal_eval(x) for x in item] for item in nLedgers] #transform list of strings to list of floats
nodes=[[literal_eval(x) for x in item] for item in nodes]

NewNodesCoord = []
dirX=1 #integer that changes the direction (X,Y) of the vector to change the x and y coordinates
dirY=1-dirX
newy1=0 #float that stores the new y coordinate at x=X1 and z=Z 
newy2=0 #float that stores the new y coordinate at x=X2 (X2>X1) and z=Z 
newx1=0 #float that stores the new x coordinate at y=Y1 and z=Z 
newx2=0 #float that stores the new x coordinate at y=Y2 (Y2>Y1) and z=Z 

from collections import defaultdict
dic1=defaultdict(list) #dictionary of X and Y pairs
dic2=defaultdict(list) #dictionary of X and Z pairs
dic3=defaultdict(list) #dictionary of Y and Z pairs

for id,x,y,z in nLedgers:
    dic1[(x,y)].append((id,z))
for key in dic1:
    dic1[key].sort( key=lambda x:float(x[1]) )

for id,x,y,z in nLedgers:
    dic2[(x,z)].append((id,y))
for key in dic2:
    dic2[key].sort( key=lambda x:float(x[1]) )
#print dic2

for id,x,y,z in nLedgers:
    dic3[(y,z)].append((id,x))
for key in dic2:
    dic3[key].sort( key=lambda x:float(x[1]) )
#print dic3

newNodes=[] #list with changed coordinates
for i,row in enumerate(nodes): #same X,Y, different Z
    id,x,y,z=row
    z_levels=[item[1] for item in dic1[(x,y)]]
    for k,l in zip(z_levels,z_levels[1:]):
        if k<=z<l:
            nodes[i][1]=x+((l-k)/400*sin(pi*(z-k)/l)+max(z_levels)/800*(z/max(z_levels)))*dirX
            nodes[i][2]=y+((l-k)/400*sin(pi*(z-k)/l)+max(z_levels)/800*(z/max(z_levels)))*dirY
            nodes[i][3]=z
            newNodes.append([nodes[i][0], nodes[i][1], nodes[i][2], nodes[i][3]])
#           break 

for i,row in enumerate(nodes):  #same X, different Y
    id,x,y,z=row
    y_levels=[item[1] for item in dic2[(x,z)]]
    z_levels=[item[1] for item in dic1[(x,y)]]
    for k,l in zip(y_levels,y_levels[1:]):
        if x==dic2.keys()[0][0] and k<y<l:
            for m,n in zip(z_levels,z_levels[1:]):
                if m==z and y==k:
                    newx1=x+((n-m)/400*sin(pi*(z-m)/n)+max(z_levels)/800*(z/max(z_levels)))*dirX
                if m==z and y==l:
                    newx2=x+(n-m)/400*sin(pi*(z-m)/n)+max(z_levels)/800*(z/max(z_levels))   
            nodes[i][1]=x+(y-k)*(newx2-newx1)/(l-k)+newx1
            nodes[i][2]=y
            nodes[i][3]=z
            newNodes.append([nodes[i][0], nodes[i][1], nodes[i][2], nodes[i][3]])

for i,row in enumerate(nodes):#same Y, different X
    id,x,y,z=row
    x_levels=[item[1] for item in dic3[(y,z)]]
    z_levels=[item[1] for item in dic1[(x,y)]]
    for k,l in zip(x_levels,x_levels[1:]):
#        print dic3.keys()[0][0]
        if y==dic3.keys()[0][0] and k<x<l: #same X, different Y
            for m,n in zip(z_levels,z_levels[1:]):
                if m==z and y==k:
                    newy1=y+((n-m)/400*sin(pi*(z-m)/n)+max(z_levels)/800*(z/max(z_levels)))*dirY
                if m==z and y==l:
                    newy2=y+((n-m)/400*sin(pi*(z-m)/n)+max(z_levels)/800*(z/max(z_levels)))*dirY  
            nodes[i][1]=x
            nodes[i][2]=y+(y-k)*(newy2-newy1)/(l-k)+newy1
            nodes[i][3]=z
            newNodes.append([nodes[i][0], nodes[i][1], nodes[i][2], nodes[i][3]])
```

The first change is working (the X,Y pair), the other two aren't working. I've got a problem in `dic2.keys()[0][0]`. I'd like to loop over the keys of dic2 and compare the value of the first key with x.

Comment: `z = sorted(z)` does nothing, (you are just binding the name `z` to a sorted version of itself, not changing it's contents) change to `z.sort()`

Comment: @jamylak: I got this error: `    z.sort()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'sort'`

Comment: oh right I forgot, you are using a `set`, wait why does it say `str` then? It's become a string somehow

Comment: You lost me at "After identifying...". After that I really cannot understand a single thing of what you are saying. Give some *examples* of the inputs and the outputs you want.

Comment: @Bakuriu: I've added some information. Hope it is more understandable.

Comment: @jpcgandre `Zlevel`s are the value of z coordinate from `datacord2` for a particular (x,y)?,  And how are going to change the values based on those conditions?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: Yes, `Zlevel` are also included in `DataCoord2`. Changing the values is the easy part: `if conditions are met: newX=oldX+function and newY=oldY +function and newZ=oldZ`

Comment: Before anything else, looks like the DATA STRUCTURE of what your doing could be improved. Is this a 3D cloud point? What do `NodeID` represent? Is it a label, or the identifier of a "layer" or "category" the point belongs to?

Comment: @heltonbiker: Yes, the list of lists represent a 3D cloud point. `NodeID` is the label of each point.

Comment: Then I would think about the very need to use an ID for a node. If you want to spatially sort the cloudpoint, then you'd use the coordinates themselves. Now let's suppose you have a model with mixed particles in a container (dust and aerosol, for example), then you'd have to identify the TYPE of particle. But if you only identify the points for the sake of identification (or other uses besides segmentation), then you'd definitely don't need to operate on ID, and you could use very efficient vectorized operations using Numpy (do you know it already?).

Comment: @heltonbiker: The list of lists I'm using as input are in reality the information of txt files. The first column is the node ID. I'll need this at the end because I'll need to replace the txt files. I think I can use your method (although I'd be grateful if you could give me an example) if there's a way of not losing the association between the nodeID and the node coordinates.

Comment: @jpcgandre I think you should take a look at Pandas Library, creating a `pandas.Frame` with your cloudpoint read from text, while using NodeID to index the rows. Or maybe ask a new question with a sample from your text file, your intended result, and the "pandas" tag. If I have time I'm gonna try to give you a working example using Pandas or Numpy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict
data1=[['173', '0.', '0.', '0.'], ['183', '1000.', '0.', '0.'], ['184', '0.', '1000.', '0.'], ['194', '1000.', '1000.', '0.'], ['195', '0.', '0.', '1000.'], ['205', '1000.', '0.', '1000.'], ['206', '0.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['216', '1000.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['217', '0.', '0.', '2000.'], ['227', '1000.', '0.', '2000.'], ['228', '0.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['238', '1000.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['239', '0.', '0.', '3000.'], ['249', '1000.', '0.', '3000.'], ['250', '0.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['260', '1000.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['261', '0.', '0.', '4000.'], ['271', '1000.', '0.', '4000.'], ['272', '0.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['282', '1000.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['283', '0.', '0.', '0.'], ['293', '0.', '1000.', '0.'], ['294', '1000.', '0.', '0.'], ['304', '1000.', '1000.', '0.'], ['305', '0.', '0.', '1000.'], ['315', '0.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['316', '1000.', '0.', '1000.'], ['326', '1000.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['327', '0.', '0.', '2000.'], ['337', '0.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['338', '1000.', '0.', '2000.'], ['348', '1000.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['349', '0.', '0.', '3000.'], ['359', '0.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['360', '1000.', '0.', '3000.'], ['370', '1000.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['371', '0.', '0.', '4000.'], ['381', '0.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['382', '1000.', '0.', '4000.'], ['392', '1000.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['436', '-1000.', '0.', '0.'], ['446', '0.', '0.', '0.'], ['447', '-1000.', '1000.', '0.'], ['457', '0.', '1000.', '0.'], ['458', '-1000.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['468', '0.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['469', '-1000.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['479', '0.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['480', '-1000.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['490', '0.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['491', '-1000.', '0.', '0.'], ['501', '-1000.', '1000.', '0.'], ['502', '-1000.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['512', '0.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['513', '-1000.', '0.', '1000.'], ['523', '0.', '0.', '1000.'], ['524', '-1000.', '0.', '2000.'], ['534', '0.', '0.', '2000.'], ['535', '-1000.', '0.', '3000.'], ['545', '0.', '0.', '3000.'], ['546', '-1000.', '0.', '4000.'], ['556', '0.', '0.', '4000.'], ['557', '-1000.', '0.', '1000.'], ['567', '-1000.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['568', '-1000.', '0.', '3000.'], ['578', '-1000.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['579', '-1000.', '0.', '2000.'], ['589', '-1000.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['590', '-1000.', '0.', '4000.'], ['600', '-1000.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['687', '0.', '2000.', '0.'], ['697', '1000.', '2000.', '0.'], ['698', '0.', '2000.', '1000.'], ['708', '1000.', '2000.', '1000.'], ['709', '0.', '2000.', '2000.'], ['719', '1000.', '2000.', '2000.'], ['720', '0.', '2000.', '3000.'], ['730', '1000.', '2000.', '3000.'], ['731', '0.', '2000.', '4000.'], ['741', '1000.', '2000.', '4000.'], ['742', '0.', '1000.', '0.'], ['752', '0.', '2000.', '0.'], ['753', '1000.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['763', '1000.', '2000.', '1000.'], ['764', '1000.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['774', '1000.', '2000.', '3000.'], ['775', '1000.', '1000.', '0.'], ['785', '1000.', '2000.', '0.'], ['786', '1000.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['796', '1000.', '2000.', '2000.'], ['797', '1000.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['807', '1000.', '2000.', '4000.'], ['808', '-1000.', '1000.', '0.'], ['818', '-1000.', '2000.', '0.'], ['819', '0.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['829', '0.', '2000.', '1000.'], ['830', '0.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['840', '0.', '2000.', '2000.'], ['841', '0.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['851', '0.', '2000.', '3000.'], ['852', '0.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['862', '0.', '2000.', '4000.'], ['863', '-1000.', '2000.', '0.'], ['873', '0.', '2000.', '0.'], ['874', '-1000.', '2000.', '1000.'], ['884', '0.', '2000.', '1000.'], ['885', '-1000.', '2000.', '2000.'], ['895', '0.', '2000.', '2000.'], ['896', '-1000.', '2000.', '3000.'], ['906', '0.', '2000.', '3000.'], ['907', '-1000.', '2000.', '4000.'], ['917', '0.', '2000.', '4000.'], ['918', '-1000.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['928', '-1000.', '2000.', '1000.'], ['929', '-1000.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['939', '-1000.', '2000.', '3000.'], ['940', '-1000.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['950', '-1000.', '2000.', '2000.'], ['951', '-1000.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['961', '-1000.', '2000.', '4000.']]
data2=[['1', '0.', '0.', '-100.'], ['2', '0.', '0.', '0.'], ['3', '0.', '0.', '4000.'], ['4', '0.', '0.', '4100.'], ['5', '0.', '0.', '100.'], ['6', '0.', '0.', '200.'], ['7', '0.', '0.', '300.'], ['8', '0.', '0.', '400.'], ['9', '0.', '0.', '500.'], ['10', '0.', '0.', '600.'], ['11', '0.', '0.', '700.'], ['12', '0.', '0.', '800.'], ['13', '0.', '0.', '900.'], ['14', '0.', '0.', '1000.'], ['15', '0.', '0.', '1100.'], ['16', '0.', '0.', '1200.'], ['17', '0.', '0.', '1300.'], ['18', '0.', '0.', '1400.'], ['19', '0.', '0.', '1500.'], ['20', '0.', '0.', '1600.'], ['21', '0.', '0.', '1700.'], ['22', '0.', '0.', '1800.'], ['23', '0.', '0.', '1900.'], ['24', '0.', '0.', '2000.'], ['25', '0.', '0.', '2100.'], ['26', '0.', '0.', '2200.'], ['27', '0.', '0.', '2300.'], ['28', '0.', '0.', '2400.'], ['29', '0.', '0.', '2500.'], ['30', '0.', '0.', '2600.'], ['31', '0.', '0.', '2700.'], ['32', '0.', '0.', '2800.'], ['33', '0.', '0.', '2900.'], ['34', '0.', '0.', '3000.'], ['35', '0.', '0.', '3100.'], ['36', '0.', '0.', '3200.'], ['37', '0.', '0.', '3300.'], ['38', '0.', '0.', '3400.'], ['39', '0.', '0.', '3500.'], ['40', '0.', '0.', '3600.'], ['41', '0.', '0.', '3700.'], ['42', '0.', '0.', '3800.'], ['43', '0.', '0.', '3900.'], ['44', '0.', '1000.', '-100.'], ['45', '0.', '1000.', '0.'], ['46', '0.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['47', '0.', '1000.', '4100.'], ['48', '0.', '1000.', '100.'], ['49', '0.', '1000.', '200.'], ['50', '0.', '1000.', '300.'], ['51', '0.', '1000.', '400.'], ['52', '0.', '1000.', '500.'], ['53', '0.', '1000.', '600.'], ['54', '0.', '1000.', '700.'], ['55', '0.', '1000.', '800.'], ['56', '0.', '1000.', '900.'], ['57', '0.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['58', '0.', '1000.', '1100.'], ['59', '0.', '1000.', '1200.'], ['60', '0.', '1000.', '1300.'], ['61', '0.', '1000.', '1400.'], ['62', '0.', '1000.', '1500.'], ['63', '0.', '1000.', '1600.'], ['64', '0.', '1000.', '1700.'], ['65', '0.', '1000.', '1800.'], ['66', '0.', '1000.', '1900.'], ['67', '0.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['68', '0.', '1000.', '2100.'], ['69', '0.', '1000.', '2200.'], ['70', '0.', '1000.', '2300.'], ['71', '0.', '1000.', '2400.'], ['72', '0.', '1000.', '2500.'], ['73', '0.', '1000.', '2600.'], ['74', '0.', '1000.', '2700.'], ['75', '0.', '1000.', '2800.'], ['76', '0.', '1000.', '2900.'], ['77', '0.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['78', '0.', '1000.', '3100.'], ['79', '0.', '1000.', '3200.'], ['80', '0.', '1000.', '3300.'], ['81', '0.', '1000.', '3400.'], ['82', '0.', '1000.', '3500.'], ['83', '0.', '1000.', '3600.'], ['84', '0.', '1000.', '3700.'], ['85', '0.', '1000.', '3800.'], ['86', '0.', '1000.', '3900.'], ['87', '1000.', '0.', '-100.'], ['88', '1000.', '0.', '0.'], ['89', '1000.', '0.', '4000.'], ['90', '1000.', '0.', '4100.'], ['91', '1000.', '0.', '100.'], ['92', '1000.', '0.', '200.'], ['93', '1000.', '0.', '300.'], ['94', '1000.', '0.', '400.'], ['95', '1000.', '0.', '500.'], ['96', '1000.', '0.', '600.'], ['97', '1000.', '0.', '700.'], ['98', '1000.', '0.', '800.'], ['99', '1000.', '0.', '900.'], ['100', '1000.', '0.', '1000.'], ['101', '1000.', '0.', '1100.'], ['102', '1000.', '0.', '1200.'], ['103', '1000.', '0.', '1300.'], ['104', '1000.', '0.', '1400.'], ['105', '1000.', '0.', '1500.'], ['106', '1000.', '0.', '1600.'], ['107', '1000.', '0.', '1700.'], ['108', '1000.', '0.', '1800.'], ['109', '1000.', '0.', '1900.'], ['110', '1000.', '0.', '2000.'], ['111', '1000.', '0.', '2100.'], ['112', '1000.', '0.', '2200.'], ['113', '1000.', '0.', '2300.'], ['114', '1000.', '0.', '2400.'], ['115', '1000.', '0.', '2500.'], ['116', '1000.', '0.', '2600.'], ['117', '1000.', '0.', '2700.'], ['118', '1000.', '0.', '2800.'], ['119', '1000.', '0.', '2900.'], ['120', '1000.', '0.', '3000.'], ['121', '1000.', '0.', '3100.'], ['122', '1000.', '0.', '3200.'], ['123', '1000.', '0.', '3300.'], ['124', '1000.', '0.', '3400.'], ['125', '1000.', '0.', '3500.'], ['126', '1000.', '0.', '3600.'], ['127', '1000.', '0.', '3700.'], ['128', '1000.', '0.', '3800.'], ['129', '1000.', '0.', '3900.'], ['130', '1000.', '1000.', '-100.'], ['131', '1000.', '1000.', '0.'], ['132', '1000.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['133', '1000.', '1000.', '4100.'], ['134', '1000.', '1000.', '100.'], ['135', '1000.', '1000.', '200.'], ['136', '1000.', '1000.', '300.'], ['137', '1000.', '1000.', '400.'], ['138', '1000.', '1000.', '500.'], ['139', '1000.', '1000.', '600.'], ['140', '1000.', '1000.', '700.'], ['141', '1000.', '1000.', '800.'], ['142', '1000.', '1000.', '900.'], ['143', '1000.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['144', '1000.', '1000.', '1100.'], ['145', '1000.', '1000.', '1200.'], ['146', '1000.', '1000.', '1300.'], ['147', '1000.', '1000.', '1400.'], ['148', '1000.', '1000.', '1500.'], ['149', '1000.', '1000.', '1600.'], ['150', '1000.', '1000.', '1700.'], ['151', '1000.', '1000.', '1800.'], ['152', '1000.', '1000.', '1900.'], ['153', '1000.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['154', '1000.', '1000.', '2100.'], ['155', '1000.', '1000.', '2200.'], ['156', '1000.', '1000.', '2300.'], ['157', '1000.', '1000.', '2400.'], ['158', '1000.', '1000.', '2500.'], ['159', '1000.', '1000.', '2600.'], ['160', '1000.', '1000.', '2700.'], ['161', '1000.', '1000.', '2800.'], ['162', '1000.', '1000.', '2900.'], ['163', '1000.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['164', '1000.', '1000.', '3100.'], ['165', '1000.', '1000.', '3200.'], ['166', '1000.', '1000.', '3300.'], ['167', '1000.', '1000.', '3400.'], ['168', '1000.', '1000.', '3500.'], ['169', '1000.', '1000.', '3600.'], ['170', '1000.', '1000.', '3700.'], ['171', '1000.', '1000.', '3800.'], ['172', '1000.', '1000.', '3900.'], ['173', '0.', '0.', '0.'], ['174', '100.', '0.', '0.'], ['175', '200.', '0.', '0.'], ['176', '300.', '0.', '0.'], ['177', '400.', '0.', '0.'], ['178', '500.', '0.', '0.'], ['179', '600.', '0.', '0.'], ['180', '700.', '0.', '0.'], ['181', '800.', '0.', '0.'], ['182', '900.', '0.', '0.'], ['183', '1000.', '0.', '0.'], ['184', '0.', '1000.', '0.'], ['185', '100.', '1000.', '0.'], ['186', '200.', '1000.', '0.'], ['187', '300.', '1000.', '0.'], ['188', '400.', '1000.', '0.'], ['189', '500.', '1000.', '0.'], ['190', '600.', '1000.', '0.'], ['191', '700.', '1000.', '0.'], ['192', '800.', '1000.', '0.'], ['193', '900.', '1000.', '0.'], ['194', '1000.', '1000.', '0.'], ['195', '0.', '0.', '1000.'], ['196', '100.', '0.', '1000.'], ['197', '200.', '0.', '1000.'], ['198', '300.', '0.', '1000.'], ['199', '400.', '0.', '1000.'], ['200', '500.', '0.', '1000.'], ['201', '600.', '0.', '1000.'], ['202', '700.', '0.', '1000.'], ['203', '800.', '0.', '1000.'], ['204', '900.', '0.', '1000.'], ['205', '1000.', '0.', '1000.'], ['206', '0.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['207', '100.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['208', '200.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['209', '300.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['210', '400.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['211', '500.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['212', '600.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['213', '700.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['214', '800.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['215', '900.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['216', '1000.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['217', '0.', '0.', '2000.'], ['218', '100.', '0.', '2000.'], ['219', '200.', '0.', '2000.'], ['220', '300.', '0.', '2000.'], ['221', '400.', '0.', '2000.'], ['222', '500.', '0.', '2000.'], ['223', '600.', '0.', '2000.'], ['224', '700.', '0.', '2000.'], ['225', '800.', '0.', '2000.'], ['226', '900.', '0.', '2000.'], ['227', '1000.', '0.', '2000.'], ['228', '0.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['229', '100.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['230', '200.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['231', '300.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['232', '400.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['233', '500.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['234', '600.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['235', '700.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['236', '800.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['237', '900.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['238', '1000.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['239', '0.', '0.', '3000.'], ['240', '100.', '0.', '3000.'], ['241', '200.', '0.', '3000.'], ['242', '300.', '0.', '3000.'], ['243', '400.', '0.', '3000.'], ['244', '500.', '0.', '3000.'], ['245', '600.', '0.', '3000.'], ['246', '700.', '0.', '3000.'], ['247', '800.', '0.', '3000.'], ['248', '900.', '0.', '3000.'], ['249', '1000.', '0.', '3000.'], ['250', '0.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['251', '100.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['252', '200.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['253', '300.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['254', '400.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['255', '500.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['256', '600.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['257', '700.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['258', '800.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['259', '900.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['260', '1000.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['261', '0.', '0.', '4000.'], ['262', '100.', '0.', '4000.'], ['263', '200.', '0.', '4000.'], ['264', '300.', '0.', '4000.'], ['265', '400.', '0.', '4000.'], ['266', '500.', '0.', '4000.'], ['267', '600.', '0.', '4000.'], ['268', '700.', '0.', '4000.'], ['269', '800.', '0.', '4000.'], ['270', '900.', '0.', '4000.'], ['271', '1000.', '0.', '4000.'], ['272', '0.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['273', '100.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['274', '200.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['275', '300.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['276', '400.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['277', '500.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['278', '600.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['279', '700.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['280', '800.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['281', '900.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['282', '1000.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['283', '0.', '0.', '0.'], ['284', '0.', '100.', '0.'], ['285', '0.', '200.', '0.'], ['286', '0.', '300.', '0.'], ['287', '0.', '400.', '0.'], ['288', '0.', '500.', '0.'], ['289', '0.', '600.', '0.'], ['290', '0.', '700.', '0.'], ['291', '0.', '800.', '0.'], ['292', '0.', '900.', '0.'], ['293', '0.', '1000.', '0.'], ['294', '1000.', '0.', '0.'], ['295', '1000.', '100.', '0.'], ['296', '1000.', '200.', '0.'], ['297', '1000.', '300.', '0.'], ['298', '1000.', '400.', '0.'], ['299', '1000.', '500.', '0.'], ['300', '1000.', '600.', '0.'], ['301', '1000.', '700.', '0.'], ['302', '1000.', '800.', '0.'], ['303', '1000.', '900.', '0.'], ['304', '1000.', '1000.', '0.'], ['305', '0.', '0.', '1000.'], ['306', '0.', '100.', '1000.'], ['307', '0.', '200.', '1000.'], ['308', '0.', '300.', '1000.'], ['309', '0.', '400.', '1000.'], ['310', '0.', '500.', '1000.'], ['311', '0.', '600.', '1000.'], ['312', '0.', '700.', '1000.'], ['313', '0.', '800.', '1000.'], ['314', '0.', '900.', '1000.'], ['315', '0.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['316', '1000.', '0.', '1000.'], ['317', '1000.', '100.', '1000.'], ['318', '1000.', '200.', '1000.'], ['319', '1000.', '300.', '1000.'], ['320', '1000.', '400.', '1000.'], ['321', '1000.', '500.', '1000.'], ['322', '1000.', '600.', '1000.'], ['323', '1000.', '700.', '1000.'], ['324', '1000.', '800.', '1000.'], ['325', '1000.', '900.', '1000.'], ['326', '1000.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['327', '0.', '0.', '2000.'], ['328', '0.', '100.', '2000.'], ['329', '0.', '200.', '2000.'], ['330', '0.', '300.', '2000.'], ['331', '0.', '400.', '2000.'], ['332', '0.', '500.', '2000.'], ['333', '0.', '600.', '2000.'], ['334', '0.', '700.', '2000.'], ['335', '0.', '800.', '2000.'], ['336', '0.', '900.', '2000.'], ['337', '0.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['338', '1000.', '0.', '2000.'], ['339', '1000.', '100.', '2000.'], ['340', '1000.', '200.', '2000.'], ['341', '1000.', '300.', '2000.'], ['342', '1000.', '400.', '2000.'], ['343', '1000.', '500.', '2000.'], ['344', '1000.', '600.', '2000.'], ['345', '1000.', '700.', '2000.'], ['346', '1000.', '800.', '2000.'], ['347', '1000.', '900.', '2000.'], ['348', '1000.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['349', '0.', '0.', '3000.'], ['350', '0.', '100.', '3000.'], ['351', '0.', '200.', '3000.'], ['352', '0.', '300.', '3000.'], ['353', '0.', '400.', '3000.'], ['354', '0.', '500.', '3000.'], ['355', '0.', '600.', '3000.'], ['356', '0.', '700.', '3000.'], ['357', '0.', '800.', '3000.'], ['358', '0.', '900.', '3000.'], ['359', '0.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['360', '1000.', '0.', '3000.'], ['361', '1000.', '100.', '3000.'], ['362', '1000.', '200.', '3000.'], ['363', '1000.', '300.', '3000.'], ['364', '1000.', '400.', '3000.'], ['365', '1000.', '500.', '3000.'], ['366', '1000.', '600.', '3000.'], ['367', '1000.', '700.', '3000.'], ['368', '1000.', '800.', '3000.'], ['369', '1000.', '900.', '3000.'], ['370', '1000.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['371', '0.', '0.', '4000.'], ['372', '0.', '100.', '4000.'], ['373', '0.', '200.', '4000.'], ['374', '0.', '300.', '4000.'], ['375', '0.', '400.', '4000.'], ['376', '0.', '500.', '4000.'], ['377', '0.', '600.', '4000.'], ['378', '0.', '700.', '4000.'], ['379', '0.', '800.', '4000.'], ['380', '0.', '900.', '4000.'], ['381', '0.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['382', '1000.', '0.', '4000.'], ['383', '1000.', '100.', '4000.'], ['384', '1000.', '200.', '4000.'], ['385', '1000.', '300.', '4000.'], ['386', '1000.', '400.', '4000.'], ['387', '1000.', '500.', '4000.'], ['388', '1000.', '600.', '4000.'], ['389', '1000.', '700.', '4000.'], ['390', '1000.', '800.', '4000.'], ['391', '1000.', '900.', '4000.'], ['392', '1000.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['393', '-1000.', '0.', '-100.'], ['394', '-1000.', '0.', '0.'], ['395', '-1000.', '0.', '4000.'], ['396', '-1000.', '0.', '4100.'], ['397', '-1000.', '0.', '100.'], ['398', '-1000.', '0.', '200.'], ['399', '-1000.', '0.', '300.'], ['400', '-1000.', '0.', '400.'], ['401', '-1000.', '0.', '500.'], ['402', '-1000.', '0.', '600.'], ['403', '-1000.', '0.', '700.'], ['404', '-1000.', '0.', '800.'], ['405', '-1000.', '0.', '900.'], ['406', '-1000.', '0.', '1000.'], ['407', '-1000.', '0.', '1100.'], ['408', '-1000.', '0.', '1200.'], ['409', '-1000.', '0.', '1300.'], ['410', '-1000.', '0.', '1400.'], ['411', '-1000.', '0.', '1500.'], ['412', '-1000.', '0.', '1600.'], ['413', '-1000.', '0.', '1700.'], ['414', '-1000.', '0.', '1800.'], ['415', '-1000.', '0.', '1900.'], ['416', '-1000.', '0.', '2000.'], ['417', '-1000.', '0.', '2100.'], ['418', '-1000.', '0.', '2200.'], ['419', '-1000.', '0.', '2300.'], ['420', '-1000.', '0.', '2400.'], ['421', '-1000.', '0.', '2500.'], ['422', '-1000.', '0.', '2600.'], ['423', '-1000.', '0.', '2700.'], ['424', '-1000.', '0.', '2800.'], ['425', '-1000.', '0.', '2900.'], ['426', '-1000.', '0.', '3000.'], ['427', '-1000.', '0.', '3100.'], ['428', '-1000.', '0.', '3200.'], ['429', '-1000.', '0.', '3300.'], ['430', '-1000.', '0.', '3400.'], ['431', '-1000.', '0.', '3500.'], ['432', '-1000.', '0.', '3600.'], ['433', '-1000.', '0.', '3700.'], ['434', '-1000.', '0.', '3800.'], ['435', '-1000.', '0.', '3900.'], ['436', '-1000.', '0.', '0.'], ['437', '-900.', '0.', '0.'], ['438', '-800.', '0.', '0.'], ['439', '-700.', '0.', '0.'], ['440', '-600.', '0.', '0.'], ['441', '-500.', '0.', '0.'], ['442', '-400.', '0.', '0.'], ['443', '-300.', '0.', '0.'], ['444', '-200.', '0.', '0.'], ['445', '-100.', '0.', '0.'], ['446', '0.', '0.', '0.'], ['447', '-1000.', '1000.', '0.'], ['448', '-900.', '1000.', '0.'], ['449', '-800.', '1000.', '0.'], ['450', '-700.', '1000.', '0.'], ['451', '-600.', '1000.', '0.'], ['452', '-500.', '1000.', '0.'], ['453', '-400.', '1000.', '0.'], ['454', '-300.', '1000.', '0.'], ['455', '-200.', '1000.', '0.'], ['456', '-100.', '1000.', '0.'], ['457', '0.', '1000.', '0.'], ['458', '-1000.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['459', '-900.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['460', '-800.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['461', '-700.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['462', '-600.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['463', '-500.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['464', '-400.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['465', '-300.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['466', '-200.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['467', '-100.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['468', '0.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['469', '-1000.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['470', '-900.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['471', '-800.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['472', '-700.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['473', '-600.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['474', '-500.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['475', '-400.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['476', '-300.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['477', '-200.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['478', '-100.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['479', '0.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['480', '-1000.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['481', '-900.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['482', '-800.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['483', '-700.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['484', '-600.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['485', '-500.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['486', '-400.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['487', '-300.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['488', '-200.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['489', '-100.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['490', '0.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['491', '-1000.', '0.', '0.'], ['492', '-1000.', '100.', '0.'], ['493', '-1000.', '200.', '0.'], ['494', '-1000.', '300.', '0.'], ['495', '-1000.', '400.', '0.'], ['496', '-1000.', '500.', '0.'], ['497', '-1000.', '600.', '0.'], ['498', '-1000.', '700.', '0.'], ['499', '-1000.', '800.', '0.'], ['500', '-1000.', '900.', '0.'], ['501', '-1000.', '1000.', '0.'], ['502', '-1000.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['503', '-900.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['504', '-800.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['505', '-700.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['506', '-600.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['507', '-500.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['508', '-400.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['509', '-300.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['510', '-200.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['511', '-100.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['512', '0.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['513', '-1000.', '0.', '1000.'], ['514', '-900.', '0.', '1000.'], ['515', '-800.', '0.', '1000.'], ['516', '-700.', '0.', '1000.'], ['517', '-600.', '0.', '1000.'], ['518', '-500.', '0.', '1000.'], ['519', '-400.', '0.', '1000.'], ['520', '-300.', '0.', '1000.'], ['521', '-200.', '0.', '1000.'], ['522', '-100.', '0.', '1000.'], ['523', '0.', '0.', '1000.'], ['524', '-1000.', '0.', '2000.'], ['525', '-900.', '0.', '2000.'], ['526', '-800.', '0.', '2000.'], ['527', '-700.', '0.', '2000.'], ['528', '-600.', '0.', '2000.'], ['529', '-500.', '0.', '2000.'], ['530', '-400.', '0.', '2000.'], ['531', '-300.', '0.', '2000.'], ['532', '-200.', '0.', '2000.'], ['533', '-100.', '0.', '2000.'], ['534', '0.', '0.', '2000.'], ['535', '-1000.', '0.', '3000.'], ['536', '-900.', '0.', '3000.'], ['537', '-800.', '0.', '3000.'], ['538', '-700.', '0.', '3000.'], ['539', '-600.', '0.', '3000.'], ['540', '-500.', '0.', '3000.'], ['541', '-400.', '0.', '3000.'], ['542', '-300.', '0.', '3000.'], ['543', '-200.', '0.', '3000.'], ['544', '-100.', '0.', '3000.'], ['545', '0.', '0.', '3000.'], ['546', '-1000.', '0.', '4000.'], ['547', '-900.', '0.', '4000.'], ['548', '-800.', '0.', '4000.'], ['549', '-700.', '0.', '4000.'], ['550', '-600.', '0.', '4000.'], ['551', '-500.', '0.', '4000.'], ['552', '-400.', '0.', '4000.'], ['553', '-300.', '0.', '4000.'], ['554', '-200.', '0.', '4000.'], ['555', '-100.', '0.', '4000.'], ['556', '0.', '0.', '4000.'], ['557', '-1000.', '0.', '1000.'], ['558', '-1000.', '100.', '1000.'], ['559', '-1000.', '200.', '1000.'], ['560', '-1000.', '300.', '1000.'], ['561', '-1000.', '400.', '1000.'], ['562', '-1000.', '500.', '1000.'], ['563', '-1000.', '600.', '1000.'], ['564', '-1000.', '700.', '1000.'], ['565', '-1000.', '800.', '1000.'], ['566', '-1000.', '900.', '1000.'], ['567', '-1000.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['568', '-1000.', '0.', '3000.'], ['569', '-1000.', '100.', '3000.'], ['570', '-1000.', '200.', '3000.'], ['571', '-1000.', '300.', '3000.'], ['572', '-1000.', '400.', '3000.'], ['573', '-1000.', '500.', '3000.'], ['574', '-1000.', '600.', '3000.'], ['575', '-1000.', '700.', '3000.'], ['576', '-1000.', '800.', '3000.'], ['577', '-1000.', '900.', '3000.'], ['578', '-1000.', '1000.', '3000.'], ['579', '-1000.', '0.', '2000.'], ['580', '-1000.', '100.', '2000.'], ['581', '-1000.', '200.', '2000.'], ['582', '-1000.', '300.', '2000.'], ['583', '-1000.', '400.', '2000.'], ['584', '-1000.', '500.', '2000.'], ['585', '-1000.', '600.', '2000.'], ['586', '-1000.', '700.', '2000.'], ['587', '-1000.', '800.', '2000.'], ['588', '-1000.', '900.', '2000.'], ['589', '-1000.', '1000.', '2000.'], ['590', '-1000.', '0.', '4000.'], ['591', '-1000.', '100.', '4000.'], ['592', '-1000.', '200.', '4000.'], ['593', '-1000.', '300.', '4000.'], ['594', '-1000.', '400.', '4000.'], ['595', '-1000.', '500.', '4000.'], ['596', '-1000.', '600.', '4000.'], ['597', '-1000.', '700.', '4000.'], ['598', '-1000.', '800.', '4000.'], ['599', '-1000.', '900.', '4000.'], ['600', '-1000.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['601', '-1000.', '1000.', '-100.'], ['602', '-1000.', '1000.', '0.'], ['603', '-1000.', '1000.', '4000.'], ['604', '-1000.', '1000.', '4100.'], ['605', '-1000.', '1000.', '100.'], ['606', '-1000.', '1000.', '200.'], ['607', '-1000.', '1000.', '300.'], ['608', '-1000.', '1000.', '400.'], ['609', '-1000.', '1000.', '500.'], ['610', '-1000.', '1000.', '600.'], ['611', '-1000.', '1000.', '700.'], ['612', '-1000.', '1000.', '800.'], ['613', '-1000.', '1000.', '900.'], ['614', '-1000.', '1000.', '1000.'], ['615', '-1000.', '1000.', '1100.'], ['616', '-1000.', '1000.', '1200.'], ['617', '-1000.', '1000.', '1300.'], ['618', '-1000.', '1000.', '1400.'], ['619', '-1000.', '1000.', '1500.'], ['620', '-1000.', '1000.', '1600.'], ['621', '-1000.', '1000.', '1700.'], ['622', '-1000.', '1000.', '1800.'], ['623', '-1000.', '1000.', '1900.']]
dic1=defaultdict(list)

for id,x,y,z in data1:
    dic1[(x,y)].append((id,z))

#sort
for key in dic1:
    dic1[key].sort( key=lambda x:float(x[1]) )

for i,row in enumerate(data2):
    id,x,y,z=row
    z_levels=[item[1] for item in dic1[(x,y)]]
    for k,l in zip(z_levels,z_levels[1:]):
       if k<=z<=l:
            #do something here 
            #data2[i][1]=None  #change x co-ordinate
            #data2[i][2]=None  #change y co-ordinate
            break
```

Comment: Thanks! Your code also works for the first part: finding and sorting different `Z levels` for each `(X,Y)` pair. But now I need to work with the results in order to change X and Y coordinates of list `DataCoord2` based on the `(x,y,z)`coordinated of each row of `DataCoord2` and on each of the `(X,Y)` pairs and associated and sorted  `Z levels`.

Comment: @jpcgandre please post some sample input output in the question body because it hard to understand what are you looking for.

Comment: @jpcgandre I've added a new answer.

Comment: I've added: `DataCoord=[[float(j) for j in i] for i in DataCoord]
DataCoord2=[[float(j) for j in i] for i in DataCoord2]`to your code to change strings to floats. 
In the #do something section I wrote: `data2[i][1]=data2[i][1]+(l-k)/400*sin(pi*(data2[i][3]-k)/l)+max(z_levels)/800*(‌​data2[i][3]/max(z_levels)) data2[i][2]=data2[i][2] data2[i][3]=data2[i][3] newNodes.append([data2[i][0], data2[i][1], data2[i][2], data2[i][3]])`
Your code works, but in the end I cheked that `len(newNodes)!=len(DataCoord2)` ans they should be the same...

Comment: @jpcgandre that may be because some `(x,y)` didn't satisy the condition, that's just a guess though.

Comment: I've just added some more code to your solution in order to do more stuff. I've a problem (I think this is more easy).

Answer (score 1):

is this what you want?
I have used just simple dict ..and in that used tuple as a key

```
result={}
for x in DataCoord:
    result.setdefault((x[1],x[2]),{})
    result[(x[1],x[2])][tuple(x)]=x[0]
```

output:

```
{('-1000.', '0.'): 
  {('436', '-1000.', '0.', '0.'): '436',
  ('491', '-1000.', '0.', '0.'): '491',
  ('513', '-1000.', '0.', '1000.'): '513',
  ('524', '-1000.', '0.', '2000.'): '524',
  ('535', '-1000.', '0.', '3000.'): '535',
.
.
.

('-1000.', '2000.'): 
  {('818', '-1000.', '2000.', '0.'): '818',
  ('863', '-1000.', '2000.', '0.'): '863',
  ('874', '-1000.', '2000.', '1000.'): '874',
  ('885', '-1000.', '2000.', '2000.'): '885',
 ..
```

Comment: Thanks. It is close. How can I work with your `result` to change, for each `(X, Y)` pair, the `X` and `Y` coordinates depending on the relative position between `Z` and each `Z level` (in another `DataCoord` I have `Z` coordinates between each `Z level`)?

Comment: @jpcgandre: can you explain that?? or just add an edit about that in your post.

Comment: is after the `After identifying and sorting the different zlevels for this (x,y) pair I'd like to do:` line.